# Installing ArcPy in Anaconda gives ImportError: Unable to locate a valid Pro or Server installation

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install ArcPy module in the Anaconda but I always get this error:

> ImportError: Unable to locate a valid Pro or Server installation to use with ArcPy. ArcPy must be installed, and match the version of the package used

I have an ArcMap version installed.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Is the "Desktop" a 32-bit ArcMap or 64-bit Pro install?

Comment: 32-bit ArcMap..

Comment: The library you are trying to install is 64-bit Python 3; it will not ever work with 32-bit Python 2.7 -- that's what the error message is saying.

Answer (score 1):

In the Description field of the [annaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/esri/arcpy) release site, it states:

> Provides the ArcPy interface to ArcGIS Pro and Server installations. Requires ArcGIS Pro or Server installed on the same machine.

A 32-bit ArcGIS install (even one with 64-bit geoprocessing) does not have a compatible Python build, and the installer recognizes this, hence the error.

In order to run that package, you must have a Python3-enabled ArcGIS release (like ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Server).